# Change Variable with Switch in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to set $url1 based on different switches that are available. I'm using this to be able to set the download URL based on location using a switch. I have stripped everything else from the script to make it quicker for anyone that's trying to help.

```
Param (
    [switch] $newyork,
    [switch] $florida,
    [switch] $california

)

$url1 = if ($newyork) {"https://newyork.com"}
    elseif ($florida) {"https://florida.com"}
    elseif ($california) {"https://california.com"}

Write-Host $url1
```

This script works perfectly fine, but I want to make sure that this is the most efficient way to do this.

In particular, I'm curious if there's any way to do this, but keep it all in the Param block. (Doing so will help me with consistency with some of my other scripts.)

Comment: Like it is now it's possible to _activate_ more than one switch. Is it that what you want? You might be better off with a single parameter with a validate set!?

Comment: I don't personally see a problem with this method in terms of efficiency. However, you could technically use all switches here and only return `https://newyork.com`.

Answer (score 2):

What you are currently doing will work, and there's probably not an issue with it regarding performance or efficiency. However, one could use one, two, or all three switches when running the script or function. Since you are doing `if` and `elseif` blocks, the first one that evaluates to `true` will have its code block executed with the remaining blocks being ignored. Below are some other approaches that can be used.

---

**Option 1: Any number of switches can be used at any time**

```
Param (
    [switch] $newyork,
    [switch] $florida,
    [switch] $california

)

if ($newyork) {"https://newyork.com"}
if ($florida) {"https://florida.com"}
if ($california) {"https://california.com"}
```

You should go with only `if` statements if you want multiple switches to be used simultaneously.

---

**Option 2: Only one switch can be used at once with parameter sets**

```
function test {
  param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='NewYork',Mandatory)]
    [switch]$newyork,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='florida',Mandatory)]
    [switch]$florida,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='california',Mandatory)]
    [switch]$california
  )
  if ($newyork) {
    "newyork"
  }
  if ($florida) {
    "florida"
  }
  if ($california) {
    "california"
  }
}
```

This requires that a single switch be used. More or less will throw an error.

---

**Option 3: Using enumerated types to force the value of a single parameter**

```
enum Location
{
    newyork
    florida
    california
}
function test {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [Location]$location
    )

    "https://{0}.com" -f $location
}
```

Enumerated types have their place. I like them for this solution. However, it will attempt to parse the input, which could cause unwanted results. For example, `test new` will bind `newyork` to `$location`.

---

**Option 4: Validating a string of a single parameter**

```
function test {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateSet('newyork','florida','california')]
        [string]$location
    )

    "https://{0}.com" -f $location
}
```

This requires that one of the three strings be entered when running the function. Using the string format operator (`-f`) does allow us to shorten the code and remove the entire `if` logic.

Comment: You could also have leveraged the ArgumentCompleter --- Register-ArgumentCompleter
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/register-argumentcompleter?view=powershell-7 --- Bring Dynamic Tab Completion to any Parameter with PowerShell ArgumentCompleters
https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-parameters-argumentcompleter --- Secret Dynamic Argument Completer
https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/secret-dynamic-argument-completer